# Using Selenium web driver, not able to take Screenshot of web page with tool-tip text displayed on it

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, tooltip, screenshot, webdriverwait

I am trying to take screen shot of the web page showing the tool tip text, but I can only see WebElement text being highlighted after mouse hover, but tool tip is not even shown up on the web page during script execution.

Here is the piece of code, that I am trying to execute. Need help to figure out what am I missing..

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException  
   {
    String URL = "https://www.rediff.com";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\bhara\\eclipse-workspace\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(URL);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    String WebElementXpath = "//*[@class='mailicon']";

    String toolTipText ;
    WebElement ToolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(WebElementXpath));

    Actions act1 = new Actions(driver);


    act1.moveToElement(ToolTipElement).build().perform();

     Robot robot = new Robot();

     Point point;
     point = ToolTipElement.getLocation();
     int x = point.getX(); 
     int y = point.getY(); 
     robot.mouseMove(x,y);

     File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("screenshot.png"));

    System.out.println( ToolTipElement.getAttribute("title"));

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you just need to add a delay ? Tooltips never appear instantly

Comment: HI, Thanks for the response! I added Thread.sleep(3000) before taking screen shot. I still did not get to see tooltip text on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any such issues in your code block as such. However if you observe the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the WebElement:

[image: title]

The text **Lightning fast free email** is the **`title`** attribute but not the **tooltip** as such. Hence through using *Actions* class to *Mouse Hover* over the element won't bring up the popup. However, I made some small changes and executed you code to get the same result as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
  options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.rediff.com/");
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='mailicon']")))).build().perform();
  File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
  FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(".\\Screenshots\\Rediffmail.png"));
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='mailicon']")).getAttribute("title"));
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Lightning fast free email
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: Rediffmail.png]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there way to have the tool tip text to come up on screen while running the screen, as it does when we manually mouse hover on and see the tool tip?