# Should we get the tooltip text before we hover-over using the Actions class or after we hover-over?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, tooltip, mouseover, webdriverwait

I apologize if I'm repeating this question.  I've been through a lot of answers on this site but I'm still not getting the tool-tip text.
I can read the title if I don't use the Actions class to hover-over and display the tool-tip.
However once I use the Actions class to display the tool-tip then title is always empty.   I don't want to get the text before I
hover-over, isn't the whole idea to read the tool-tip text that is displayed?

```
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/");


WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='/resources/demos/tooltip/default.html']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("age"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).perform();  (I've also tried clickAndHold method)
WebElement toolTip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='age']"));

// To get the tool tip text and assert
String toolTipText = toolTip.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println("toolTipText-->"+toolTipText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150918/using-selenium-web-driver-not-able-to-take-screenshot-of-web-page-with-tool-tip/59151542#59151542) are extracted only after [mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526819/how-to-mouse-hover-over-different-images-with-dynamic-xpaths-through-selenium-ja/54529255#54529255) is performed.

To print the [tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip) **Hover the field to see the tooltip.** as the desired element is within a `<iframe>` you need to:

- `scrollIntoView()` the desired [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719676/how-to-get-total-number-of-nested-frames-inside-the-frame)
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element/50621712#50621712) for *visibilityOfElementLocated()* of the element you need to [Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261078/how-to-mouse-hover-using-java-through-selenium-webdriver-and-java/47261894#47261894).
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693634/why-do-some-elements-exist-but-not-interactable-displayed/57699893#57699893) for *visibilityOfElementLocated()* for the element from where you need to retrieve the [tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412742/how-to-extract-the-tooltip-text-within-an-angular-7-application-using-selenium/55414271#55414271):
- You can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
  options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
  options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
  WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/");
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[@class='entry-title']"))));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='/resources/demos/tooltip/default.html']")));
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='age']")))).build().perform();
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='age']//following::div[text()]"))).getText());
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  However this is still incorrect text."Hover the field to see the tool-tip." is not the tool-tip text, tool tip text is "We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.

Comment: @zara that was my bad, fixed it. Retest and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks, yes this worked.  

Last question:
I see the tool tip text "We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." on multiple places in the DOM.  How did you know
to get the text from By.xpath("//input[@id='age']//following::div[text()]".   I'd been trying to get the text by using
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='age']")).getAttribute("title"); (obviously I was wrong)


<input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">
<div style="display: none;">We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.</div>

Comment: @zara The tooltip texts are in the following `<div>` which becomes visible only when you mouse over the textbox which fires an event.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense